# Can't access turtlebot through ttyUSB0

Tags: ros, usb, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I think that ROS can't access my Create... Is not possible see informations about the robot in turtlebot_dashboard, like battery and sensors status, but is possible to see netbook battery status, then I can conclude that the connection Workstation-netbook is ok, the problem could be between the netbook and Create. The status of all sensors in turtlebot_dashboard is Stale, except the netbook battery.

I'm using a serial-usb converter, because my Create uses a serial-serial cable. Could it be the problem?

Using "dmesg" and "lsusb" commands, I can see that my converter is properly connected at ttyUSB0. And I've tried to change the default_port in turtlebot_node.py to another USB and serial ports, but the error continues.

Thanks in advance,
Lucas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11185/can%27t-access-turtlebot-through-ttyusb0/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I had the same problem with the ATHEN USB serial cable.
Here is how I solved it:

Add the following line in the /etc/udev/rules.d/52-turtlebot.rules:

ATTRS{idProduct}=="2008",ATTRS{idVendor}=="0557",MODE="666",GROUP="turtlebot"

2008 and 0557 is either the vendor or product id. You can find that out from lsusb.
The problem is that the ttyUSB0 does not have the approprite permission.

---

Originally posted by [dvbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1076/dvbot/) with karma: 86 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-11-25**:
Have you tried to edit the file as a superuser (root)?

**Comment by [MovieMaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1184/moviemaker/) on 2011-11-23**:
I am having the same darn problem that I had on the other one.  I can pull up the file and make changes, but I cannot save the new file.

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-09-13**:
Thanks a lot!!!! Now everything is ok on my turtlebot!

**Comment by [Ozkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2258/ozkan/) on 2012-05-02**:
I had a similar problem. I followed the instructions here, and got my turtlebot working for a day. I shutdown everything at the weekend. On monday,  I was back to zero. I am getting "Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0" What can cause this?

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-06-04**:
Hi is GROUP="xxx" referring to the login account?

**Comment by [vikiboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/19024/vikiboy/) on 2014-06-30**:
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

What shall be my required code ? and could u tell me the parameters for GROUP and MODE ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem, and I'd like to add something to dvbot's extremely helpful response.  I couldn't communicate to the my turtlebot netbook, and my Turtlebot Dashboard was all gray.  Under Diagnostic, I had the error:
*TurtleBot Node: Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.*

When trying to implement dvbot's recommendation, I realized my turtlebot netbook didn't have the file /etc/udev/rules.d/52-turtlebot.rules, and I did not have permission to create it.  I went [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-edit-etc-udev-rules-d-40-basic-permissions-rules-file-705646/), and found good instructions from tredegar (halfway down the page) in how to overcome the problem.  For your convenience, I am recopying some of tredegar's recommendation.  To become root issue the command:

```
sudo -i
```

Then to create the file you can use the command

```
gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/52-turtlebot.rules
```

or use your favorite editor.  Once you populate the content with [dvbot's code](http://answers.ros.org/question/11185/cant-access-turtlebot-through-ttyusb0?answer=16585#answer-container-16585), restart udev:

```
/etc/init.d/udev  restart
```

I'm still very new to this, but I do know this worked for me: once I restarted udev, my Turtlebot Dashboard went from gray to greens and reds.  Both my workstation and turtlebot netbook are running Ubuntu 11.10 and ros electric.   Hope this is useful.

---

Originally posted by [trroy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1847/trroy/) with karma: 21 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2